# Why is Blender recording keyframes any time I transform an object?

Tags: animation

[image: I Don't want to animate]

[image: This is Getting Old]

What have I done that makes it record every movement as an animation??

It is so annoying to have to go back and 'Clear Animation Data' on each and every object every time I tweak it this way or that.

I know I must have turned something on or off while trying to find something else but I don't know what it is.

Here are my specifics...

## Blender:

version: 2.83.3, branch: master, commit date: 2020-07-22 06:01, hash: 353e5bd7493e, type: Release
build date: 2020-07-22, 04:04:56
platform: Windows
binary path: 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\blender.exe'
build cflags: /W3 /w34062 /w34115 /w34189 /wd4018 /wd4146 /wd4065 /wd4127 /wd4181 /wd4200 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4800 /wd4828 /wd4996 /wd4661 /we4013 /we4133 /we4431 /w35038 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /nologo /J /Gd /MP /bigobj -openmp
build cxxflags: /W3 /w34062 /w34115 /w34189 /wd4018 /wd4146 /wd4065 /wd4127 /wd4181 /wd4200 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4800 /wd4828 /wd4996 /wd4661 /we4013 /we4133 /we4431 /w35038 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /nologo /J /Gd /MP /EHsc /bigobj /permissive- /Zc:twoPhase- -openmp
build linkflags: /MACHINE:X64  /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /STACK:2097152,70656 /INCREMENTAL:NO  /ignore:4049 /ignore:4217 /ignore:4221
build system: CMake

## Python:

version: 3.7.4 (default, Feb 17 2020, 16:23:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
file system encoding: utf-8:surrogatepass
paths:

Comment: have you turned on the Auto Keying option in the Timeline? (red dot button)

Comment: Well, it looks like the button is activated but how do I deactivate it??

Comment: Nevermind...just click it.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you have turned on the [auto keying](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/editors/timeline.html#animation-editors-timeline-autokeyframe) on top of the timeline. Click on it again to switch it off[image]

If you have used it recently on one or two objects just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to undo everything.Otherwise press<kbd>A</kbd>  to select everything , hover your pointer over the timeline press<kbd>A</kbd> again to select all keyframes and press <kbd>x</kbd> to delete all keyframes .Now you can reposition or rescale each object.*ta-dah*!!